# Trouble with LIKE CONCAT in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `users` and `tabletop_questions`. The `users` table has a column called `institution_primary_function` and `tabletop_questions` has a column called `target_institutions`.  An example value for `users.institution_primary_function` = `C` and an example value for tabletop_questions.target_institutions = `A,B,C,D,E,F`.

I am trying to return only those rows where the value for `users.institution_primary_function` is contained in `tabletop_questions.target_institutions` (comma delimited list) using the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM tabletop_questions
LEFT JOIN users
  ON users.institution_primary_function 
  LIKE CONCAT( '%,', tabletop_questions.target_institutions, ',%' )
```

However, with this query, every row from the `tabletop_questions` table is returned with all the values from the joined `users` table as `NULL`.  Could you please advise me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: To answer your specific question you should use `INNER JOIN` if you only want to return rows where there is a match. To answer a broader question, you are going wrong by trying to store multiple values in a single column. Normalise your database and use a [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your data because searching through a comma-delimited string is not efficient. Yet, MySQL includes a function for this called [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to only return matching records.

```
SELECT * FROM tabletop_questions
INNER JOIN users
  ON FIND_IN_SET(users.institution_primary_function,
    tabletop_questions.target_institutions)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and advice about normalizing the data first!